# PHP Filter Sanitize Number Int removing signs

Tags: php, sanitization

I'm trying to sanitize a string of numbers, removing also the minus and addition signs. I've been researching but I didn't find anything.

- Basically what I want is the following:

> Being, for example $_GET = "%'¡-8"

```
$foo = filter_var($_GET, FILTER_SANITIZE_WHATEVER)
```

- Expected

> return 8

Comment: You can't make it function differently than it was designed. You'll just have to use `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT` and add an additional action that extracts the value you want, such as [`abs`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php).

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use preg_replace to remove all non-numeric characters before casting to INT. This ensures that a valid numeric string is passed before attempting to sanitize as normal.

```
    $string = "%'¡-8"
    $value = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $string);
    $sanitized = (int) $value;
```